# Terraform azurerm_data_factory vsts_configuration failing with Error: Error configuring Repository for Data Factory

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to set up the code repository in Azure Data Factory using Terraform deploying with Azure Cloud Shell with contributor access following this: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/data_factory.html#vsts_configuration

I'm getting the error message:

> Error: Error configuring Repository for Data Factory "adf-name"
>   (Resource Group "rg-name"):
>   datafactory.FactoriesClient#ConfigureFactoryRepo: Failure responding
>   to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service
>   returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The
>   client 'xxx@xxx.com' with object id 'xxxxx' does not have
>   authorization to perform action
>   'Microsoft.DataFactory/locations/configureFactoryRepo/action' over
>   scope '/subscriptions/xxxxxx' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted,
>   please refresh your credentials.

I've de-sensitised the client, object id and scope.

I am able to set up the code repository in the portal, but fails when I try and run the terraform in the Azure Cloud Shell. Has anyone seen this error message before or know how to get past it?

Code snip it:

```
`provider "azurerm" {
  version = "=2.3.0"
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {
  name                = var.adf_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  vsts_configuration {
    account_name      = var.account_name
    branch_name       = var.branch_name
    project_name      = var.project_name
    repository_name   = var.repo_name
    root_folder       = var.root_folder
    tenant_id         = var.tenant_id
  }
}`
```

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Please give the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom role had to be added for the action ‘ Microsoft.DataFactory/locations/configureFactoryRepo/action’ and assigned to the service principal. Contributor role itself was not enough to set up the code repository for Azure Data Factory using Terraform azurerm.

Comment: A fix for this issue has now been released in Version 2.8.0 of AzureRm provider: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/v2.8.0/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: No fix is available in version 2.8.0. I still have the same error while using this version of terraform

Comment: My mistake that was a fix for needing subscription level permissions to create a key vault. There is still no fix for this issue. I have created a github issue https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/6484